# validate no duplicates in streamfield

Tags: django, wagtail

Need to create a long scroll page with sidebar nav for on-page navigation. This means each heading will have an id. Can I validate at the streamfield level to make sure a user doesn't put in a duplicate id?

Edit:
The headings are defined as such:

```
class HeadingOneBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    id = blocks.RegexBlock(regex=r'^\S*$', help_text='No spaces or special characters')
    heading = blocks.CharBlock()

    class Meta:
        template = 'base/heading_one.html'
        icon = 'title'
        label = 'h1'
```

And the page:

```
class LongScrollPage(Page):
    banner_text = RichTextField()
    description = RichTextField()
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading1', HeadingOneBlock()),
        ('heading2', HeadingTwoBlock()),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock(features=['bold', 'italic', 'ol', 'ul', 'link', 'image', 'hr'])),
        ('collapsible_panel', CollapsiblePanelBlock()),
        ('table', TableBlock(template='base/tables.html')),
    ], blank=True, null=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('banner_text'),
        FieldPanel('description'),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

Is there a way to validate at the 'body' level? I know I can validate at the block level, but how do I then make sure the ids are unique?

Comment: Could you please put a bit more information in this question, for example the code you are using so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a custom `validators` attribute on your `StreamField`.

You can read more about [Django Form Validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/) for info.

Also, the `value` presented to the validator is an instance of `[StreamValue](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/core/blocks/stream_block.py#L324)` which has an attribute `stream_data` which contains a list of tuples. The first item in each tuple is the label you have given the block (eg. heading1, heading2, paragraph in your example). The second item is a `StructValue` instance where each sub-blocks value can be accessed by their key, `hence data[1].get('id')` in the example below.

Validator code (can also be in your models.py file):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from wagtail.core.blocks import StreamBlockValidationError # plus all blocks imported here


def validate_ids_in_headings(value):
    # value.stream_data is a list of tuples
    # first item in each tuple is the label (eg. 'heading1' or 'paragraph')
    # second item in each tuple is a StructValue which is like an ordered dict
    items = [
        data[1].get('id')
        for data in value.stream_data
        if 'heading' in data[0]
    ]
    if len(set(items)) != len(items):
        # sets can only be unique so - the items are are not unique
        # must raise special StreamBlockValidationError error like this
        raise StreamBlockValidationError(
            non_block_errors=ValidationError(
                'All headings must have unique ID values: %(value)s',
                code='invalid',
                params={'value': items},
            )
        )
    # if valid, do nothing
```

Revised model code:

```
# using one HeadingBlock class here as you can define template/label within the StreamField
class HeadingBlock(StructBlock):
    id = RegexBlock(regex=r'^\S*$', help_text='No spaces or special characters')
    heading = CharBlock()
    class Meta:
        icon = 'title'


body = StreamField([
    ('heading1', HeadingBlock(label='h1', template='base/heading_one.html')), # note: label/template set here
    ('heading2', HeadingBlock(label='h2', template='base/heading_two.html')), # note: label/template set here
    ('paragraph', RichTextBlock(features=['bold', 'italic', 'ol', 'ul', 'link', 'image', 'hr'])),
    ('collapsible_panel', CollapsiblePanelBlock()),
    ('table', TableBlock(template='base/tables.html')),
 # validators set here, must be within a list - even if one item, removed null=True as not needed
], blank=True, validators=[validate_ids_in_headings])
```

This will throw an error shown to the user.

Unfortunately this will not highlight the tab (with an error indicator) but it will show the error at the start of the 'Body' block with the specific error text see [Issue 4122](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4122).

I have tested this on a BakeryDemo, Wagtail 1.13, using Python 3.

Comment: So I ran into a weird issue when trying to do this in wagtail 2.4. It appears that Wagtail saves out the stream data two different ways depending on how you're saving the model. If you click "Save Draft" it saves out the data as a list of tuples. However, if you click "publish" it saves out the data as a list of dict's. I had to add a simple check to see what the data was for "Save as draft" and "Publish to work"

`all(isinstance(data, tuple) for data in value.stream_data)`
and
`all(isinstance(data, dict) for data in value.stream_data)`

Comment: I actually submitted that as a bug to wagtail, and you can see there response here. https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5085

basically you shouldn't be accessing the `stream_data` directly, and you should just be accessing it as "value"

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently [not supposed to access stream_data directly](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/5085) that way according to the authors of wagtail, but the above code can be modified slightly to get the same effect.

```
def validate_ids_in_headings(value):
# value.stream_data is a list of tuples
# first item in each tuple is the label (eg. 'heading1' or 'paragraph')
# second item in each tuple is a StructValue which is like an ordered dict
items = [
    data.value.get('id')
    for data in value
]
if len(set(items)) != len(items):
    # sets can only be unique so - the items are are not unique
    # must raise special StreamBlockValidationError error like this
    raise StreamBlockValidationError(
        non_block_errors=ValidationError(
            'All headings must have unique ID values: %(value)s',
            code='invalid',
            params={'value': items},
        )
    )
# if valid, do nothing
```

I think this should take care of your case, and it's not reliant on a field that isn't supposed to be accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

For wagtail version 2.11.8 this have worked for me. (This is a modification of earlier answers)

```
"""Streamfield uniqueness validator"""
def streamfield_uniqueness_validator(value):
    # value.stream_data is a list of tuples
    # first item in each tuple is the label (eg. 'recipient_email')
    # second item in each tuple is the actual value of field 
    # third item in each tuple is the id of tuple or dict
    items = [
        data[1].lower()
        for data in value.stream_data
    ]
    print(items)
    if len(set(items)) != len(items):
        # sets can only be unique so - the items are are not unique
        # must raise special StreamBlockValidationError error like this
        raise StreamBlockValidationError(
            non_block_errors=ValidationError(
                'Cannot add same email on multiple fields: %(value)s',
                code='invalid',
                params={'value': items},
            )
        )
```

In my model:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    stream_fileds = StreamField([('stream_filed', blocks.CharBlock())], validators=[streamfield_uniqueness_validator])
```